# NodeJS app crashes with an out of memory error but it looks like it has plenty left

Tags: node.js

I am trying to debug an out of memory error in NodeJS.

My script fetches data and pushes it into an array. It looks like this:

```
class Fetcher {
  async fetchAll () {
    const hits = []
    let page = 1
    while (true) {
      const result = await fetchData(page)
      hits.push(...result)
      if (!result.length) {
        break
      }
      page++
    }
    return hits
  }
}
```

When running this on a rather long database, I'm facing an out of memory error on pages 50+ (all the pages are approximately of the same size):

[image]

If I set up the `--max-old-space-size` to 8096, the error disappears. If I set it up to 2048, the error rises again.

However, I'm sure that my data is not that space consuming, and I am trying to see what operation exactly is taking so much space so I tried to debug memory usage with a function like this:

```
const printMemory = (logger: Logger) => {
  const formatMemory = memory => {
    return `${Math.round(memory / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100} MB`
  }
  const used = process.memoryUsage();
  const v8HeapStatistics = v8.getHeapStatistics()
  logger.debug(`V8 [used_heap_size]: ${formatMemory(v8HeapStatistics.used_heap_size)}`)
  logger.debug(`V8 [total_available_size]: ${formatMemory(v8HeapStatistics.total_available_size)}`)
  for (let key in used) {
    logger.debug(`${key} ${formatMemory(used[key])}`);
  }
}
```

This function is supposed to print the memory usage by the process and by V8.

When I run this function inside the loop (where the application crashes), it never exceeds 250MB of usage even if the memory usage grows over time. Example on the last loop before crash:

[image]

I'd really like to see something like `v8.getHeapStatistics().total_available_size` get closer to 0 just before the crash in order to debug my code.

**Why is my app crashing with an out of memory error, even if it looks like I still have plenty of available memory?**

Comment: I finally succeeded in finding when the memory was going crazy by using the `--trace-gc` flag